# gdb C code in linux - Address out of bounds

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    char strA[80] = {"string to be used for demonstration purposes."};
    char strB[80];

    int main(void){
      char *pA;      //A pointer to type char
      char *pB;      //Another pointer to type char
      puts(strA);    //Show string A
      pA = strA;     //Point pA to string A
      puts(pA);      //Show what pA is pointing to
      //printf("pA = %s",  pA);
      pB = strB;     //Point pB to string B           
      putchar('\n'); //Move down one line on the screen

      while(*pA != '\0'){
        *pB++ = *pA++;
      }

      *pB = '\0';
      puts(strB);    //Show string B on the screen

      return 0;

    }
```

now I use gdb for debugging and I do following steps:

```
gdb str
break main
run
x/s $esp
```

but here I get the "Address out if bounds" error...
could any body tell me how I can solve it?
thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be `puts(*pA)`? To do something with pointers, you need them to point there?

Comment: now I see the warning:passing argument 1 of ‘puts’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: @chrisk No, pA is already a pointer, and it's assigne to strA

Comment: You need to use the `backtrace` (or `bt`) command in `gdb`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch thanks

Comment: @nos, ah, right, a string is a pointer, too. Forgot that nuance. Morteza, looking over the code again, there shouldn't be a warning but I have zero experience in this exact environment; my latest work is compiling c/c++ via gcc in Windows for use on Arduino and ChipKIT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're on a 64 bit machine, $esp is a 32 bit register. You'll want to do `x/s` $rsp